# Extra blank lines in Elixir logging?

Tags: elixir

When I run my Elixir app with `_build/prod/rel/foo/bin/foo foreground`, the console logging has extra blank lines in it:

```
16:22:37.911 [info]  GET /

16:22:37.911 [info]  Sent 200 in 30µs

16:22:37.975 [info]  GET /favicon.ico

16:22:37.975 [info]  Sent 401 in 30µs
```

I'm using plug (no Phoenix) with `Plug.Logger`; the release was built with distillery. I've not done anything specific to configure logging.

How do I get rid of the blank lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the logger format in elixir, which by default [contains a newline before and after every line](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.2/lib/logger/lib/logger/formatter.ex#L46). 
Override it by adding this to your `config.exs`:

```
config :logger, :console,
  format: "$time $metadata[$level] $levelpad$message\n"
```

More info about the default logger: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.2/lib/logger/lib/logger/formatter.ex